# select() can't handle large amounts of data

Tags: select, winsock

So I've been (shamefully) using TerminateThread as a substitute for a proper timeout on the recv() function in my code. I just implemented select(), for good practice, but it can't seem to handle the size and speed that I need to receive the data.

```
DWORD WINAPI recv_low(LPVOID randparam) {
    fd_set fd;
    timeval timeout;
    FD_ZERO(&fd);
    FD_SET(UseSocket,&fd);
    timeout.tv_sec = 5;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    int sel = 0;
    iResult2 = 0;
    sel = select (UseSocket+1,&fd,NULL,NULL,&timeout);
    if (sel != 0 ) {
        iResult2 = recv(UseSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

There's the code for the receiving function with the proper timeout.
It works fine for small amounts of data, but when I kick it up and start receiving a buffer of size 65535 per second, it crashes completely and my program exits (oddly enough, with return code 0).

However, if I use my old method:

```
DWORD WINAPI recv_low(LPVOID randparam) {
    iResult2 = 0;
    iResult2 = recv(UseSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    DWORD dwrecvthreadId;
    HANDLE recvthread = CreateThread(NULL,0,recv_low,NULL,0,&dwrecvthreadId);
    WaitForSingleObject(recvthread, 5000);
    if (iResult2 > 0) //Do stuff
    else if ( iResult2 == 0 ) {
        TerminateThread(recvthread, 0);
    }
}
```

It works perfectly as expected; it receives the data without exiting.

Now as to why this happens, I have not the slightest clue. I tried to walk backwards and see what else in my code could be causing my program to exit with return code 0, but I haven't been able to find where it actually trips up and returns.
I'm forced to believe it has to do with select(), or at least my usage of it.

Anyone have any tips?
(And yes, I apologize for the improper pseudo-ish code. I'm not about to post the insanely sized main function of my program.)

EDIT: Further developments; the source of the problem is something to do with select(). I've managed to find that when I send large buffers (using the mechanism with select() I have set up above), recv() doesn't read all the data which it has been sent. For example, I sent 6 "messages", all containing 65530 bytes (just for good measure). recv() would then tell me how many it read. The first buffer was read as 12524 bytes, the next at 14952, and so on in an arbitrary fashion. That seems to be the base of my issues.

Comment: When `select()` returns `!= 0`, is it actually returning `-1` (`SOCKET_ERROR`), or is it returning `>0`?  You are calling `recv()` in both cases, but you should not be calling `recv()` if `select()` returns -1. Aside from that, where is `recvbuf` allocated, and where is `recvbuflen` initialized? And is `UseSocket` running in blocking or non-blocking mode? If blocking, an alternative to `select()` would be to use `setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO)` to set a blocking timeout on `recv()` itself.

Comment: If your code is crashing, then you are accessing invalid memory.  Did you try using a debugger to find out where and why?

Comment: Well, it's not crashing. It's returning. Returning with code `0`. I can't for the life of me find why. The parent function of the function described here as `main` doesn't even have a control path where `0` is returned.
BUT, this only happens when I use `select()`

Comment: What is returning 0 exactly? If `select()` is returning 0 than it is timing out, meaning there is no data present on the socket(s) you are waiting on.  If `recv()` is returning 0, then the socket has been gracefully disconnected by the other party (assuming `recvbuflen` is not 0).

Comment: No, actually my whole process is returning `0`. Like, my main function. For which oddly enough, `0` isn't even one of the options for a control path to return.

--Wait, yes it is. My bad. I managed to overlook a `return 0;` at the end of the function. But that still raises the question, how exactly does it manage to get there?
The receiving function is set up in an infinite loop; if the receiving thread dies (for whatever reason) it is automatically restarted. The infinite loop seems to be ending, thus my process exiting "peacefully".

Comment: Well, let's overlook that shall we? The source of the problem is something to do with `select()`. I've managed to find that when I send large buffers (using the mechanism with `select()` I have set up above), `recv()` doesn't read all the data which it has been sent. For example, I sent 6 "messages", all containing 65530 bytes (just for good measure). `recv()` would then tell me how many it read. The first buffer was read as 12524 bytes, the next at 14952, and so on in an arbitrary fashion. That seems to be the base of my issues.

Comment: That is perfectly normal behavior for TCP. TCP is stream-based, not message-based. There is no 1-to-1 relationship between `send()` and `recv()`. You must account for that, and you must pay attention to their return values. If `send()` returns fewer bytes than expected, all `send()` again to send the rest. If `recv()` returns fewer bytes than expected, call `recv()` again to read the rest. And you MUST design your protocol to know how much data is being sent per "message", whether that is by using fixed-length "messages", size-prefixed "messages", or "end-of-message" markers.

Comment: Hmm. I never knew. But I'm left wondering why it does work without `select()`. I've been using it without that for quite a while now with no anomalies. Every 65535 sent results in the client receiving 65535. But `select()`... It seems to have the effect you describe.
Well nonetheless, thank you so much for your help. If you just copy that into an answer I'll mark it up as correct :) . If not I'll do it myself and give you credit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66170/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-phixle).